# Representing an indefinite integral as a definite one

Tags: integration

My notes seem to imply that $\displaystyle\int f(x) dx=\int_0^{x}f(s)ds + C$

Assuming this is correct, take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

$\displaystyle\int f(x) dx=lnx+a$

$\displaystyle\int_0^{x}f(s)ds + C=lnx-ln (0)+C$

which are not equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

Your notes are (almost) right, only in need of two slight additions. I will assume you know that there are integrals that are not well-defined, including $\int_0^1{\frac{1}{x}}\,dx$.

The actual true statement is that $\int{f(x)}\,dx=\int_a^x{f(s)}\,ds+C$ for **any** real number $a$... so long as $f$ is continuous on the interval $\left[a,x\right]$. This is called the [first fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part). What went wrong here is that since $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined for $x=0$, it's only continuous on the interval $\left(0,1\right]$, not on $\left[0,1\right]$ - and therefore, the first fundamental theorem doesn't apply!

In fact, the specific example you've noticed here is one of the classic counterexamples used to prove that continuity on the entire interval $[a,x]$ is necessary for the first fundamental theorem.